# Finding the mode from an user-input array if there are multiple modes or no mode

Tags: java, arrays, mode

I'm working on a project that prompts the user to create and fill an array with integers, then displays the mean, mode, median, and standard deviation of that array. It starts by asking the user what the size of the array will be, to which the number entered will declare and initialize the array. The program will then iterate several times asking the user to declare an integer value, and each value will be stored into the array until the array is filled. The program will then print the contents of the array, as well as the mean, mode, median, and standard deviation.

I have a code that seems to meet all these requirements. However, one thing I am struggling on is the mode. While it does print out the most repeated number in the array, it doesn't take into account multiple modes with the same number of repetitions, nor does it take into account what will happen if there is no mode.

Right now, if two numbers are entered twice each, the mode displayed is the first number to be repeated more than once. For example, if I have an array size of 10 integers, and the integers I enter are 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, it will print out "2.0" for the mode instead of printing both "2.0" and "3.0." If there is no mode, it simply enters the number first entered, rather than saying "None."

What would be the best course of action to go about accomplishing this?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class ArrayStatistics {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double total = 0;
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Enter the size of your array >> ");
    int size = input.nextInt();
    double[] myArray = new double[size];
    System.out.print("Enter the integer values >> ");
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        myArray[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
    System.out.println("\nIntegers:");
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        System.out.println(myArray[i]);
        }
    
    double mean = calculateMean(myArray);
    System.out.println("\nMean: " + mean);
    
    double mode = calculateMode(myArray);
    System.out.println("Mode: " + mode);
    
    double median = calculateMedian(myArray);
    System.out.println("Median: " + median);
    
    double SD = calculateSD(myArray);
    System.out.format("Standard Deviation: %.6f", SD);
    }

public static double calculateMean(double myArray[]) {
    int sum = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
        sum = (int) (sum + myArray[i]);
    }
    double mean = ((double) sum) / (double)myArray.length;
    
    return mean;
}

public static double calculateMode(double myArray[]) {
    int modeCount = 0;
    int mode = 0;
    int currCount = 0;
    
    for(double candidateMode : myArray) {
        currCount = 0;
        for(double element : myArray) {
            if(candidateMode == element) {
                currCount++;
            }
        }
        if(currCount > modeCount) {
            modeCount = currCount;
            mode = (int) candidateMode;
        }
    }
    return mode;
}

public static double calculateMedian(double myArray[]) {
    Arrays.sort(myArray);
    
    int val = myArray.length/2;
    double median = ((myArray[val]+myArray[val-1])/2.0);
    
    return median;
}

public static double calculateSD(double myArray[]) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    double standardDeviation = 0.0;
    int length = myArray.length;
    for(double num : myArray) {
        sum += num;
        }
    double mean = sum/length;
    for(double num : myArray) {
        standardDeviation += Math.pow(num - mean, 2);
        }
    return Math.sqrt(standardDeviation/length);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First the code, then the explanations.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ArrayStatistics {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int total = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the size of your array >> ");
        int size = input.nextInt();
        int[] myArray = new int[size];
        Map<Integer, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<>();
        System.out.print("Enter the integer values >> ");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            myArray[i] = input.nextInt();
            if (frequencies.containsKey(myArray[i])) {
                int frequency = frequencies.get(myArray[i]);
                frequencies.put(myArray[i], frequency + 1);
            }
            else {
                frequencies.put(myArray[i], 1);
            }
            total += myArray[i];
        }
        System.out.println("\nIntegers:");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.println(myArray[i]);
        }

        double mean = calculateMean(size, total);
        System.out.println("\nMean: " + mean);

        List<Integer> mode = calculateMode(frequencies);
        System.out.println("Mode: " + mode);

        double median = calculateMedian(myArray);
        System.out.println("Median: " + median);

        double stdDev = calculateSD(mean, total, size, myArray);
        System.out.format("Standard Deviation: %.6f", stdDev);
    }

    public static double calculateMean(int count, int total) {
        double mean = ((double) total) / count;
        return mean;
    }

    public static List<Integer> calculateMode(Map<Integer, Integer> frequencies) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> sorted = frequencies.entrySet()
                                                  .stream()
                                                  .sorted((e1, e2) -> e2.getValue() - e1.getValue())
                                                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(),
                                                                            e -> e.getValue(),
                                                                            (i1, i2) -> i1,
                                                                            LinkedHashMap::new));
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = sorted.keySet().iterator();
        Integer first = iterator.next();
        Integer val = sorted.get(first);
        List<Integer> modes = new ArrayList<>();
        if (val > 1) {
            modes.add(first);
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Integer next = iterator.next();
                Integer nextVal = sorted.get(next);
                if (nextVal.equals(val)) {
                    modes.add(next);
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return modes;
    }

    public static double calculateMedian(int myArray[]) {
        Arrays.sort(myArray);

        int val = myArray.length / 2;
        double median = ((myArray[val] + myArray[val - 1]) / 2.0);

        return median;
    }

    public static double calculateSD(double mean, int sum, int length, int[] myArray) {
        double standardDeviation = 0.0;
        for (double num : myArray) {
            standardDeviation += Math.pow(num - mean, 2);
        }
        return Math.sqrt(standardDeviation / length);
    }
}
```

In order to determine the mode(s), you need to keep track of the occurrences of integers entered into your array. I use a `Map` to do this. I also calculate the total while entering the integers. I use this total in methods that require it, for example `calculateMean`. Seems like extra work to recalculate the total each time you need it.

You are dealing with integers, so why declare `myArray` as array of `double`? Hence I changed it to array of `int`.

Your question was how to determine the mode(s). Consequently I refactored method `calculatMode`. In order to determine the mode(s), you need to interrogate the frequencies, hence the method parameter. Since you claim that there can be zero, one or more than one modes, the method returns a `List`. First I sort the `Map` entries according to the value, i.e. the number of occurrences of a particular integer in `myArray`. I sort the entries in descending order. Then I collect all the sorted entries to a `LinkedHashMap` since that is a map that stores its entries in the order in which they were added. Hence the first entry in the `LinkedHashMap` will be the integer with the most occurrences. If the number of occurrences of the first map entry is 1 (one), that means there are no modes (according to this [definition](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/meanmode.htm) that I found):

> If no number in the list is repeated, then there is no mode for the list.

In the case of no modes, method `calculateMode` returns an empty `List`.

If the number of occurrences of the first entry is more than one, I add the integer to the `List`. Then I iterate through the remaining map entries and add the integer to the `List` if its occurrences equals that of the first map entry. As soon as the number of occurrences in an entry does not equal that of the first entry, I exit the `while` loop. Now `List` contains all the integers in `myArray` with the highest number of occurrences.

Here is a sample run (using example data from your question):

```
Enter the size of your array >> 10
Enter the integer values >> 1 2 2 3 3 4 5 6 7 8

Integers:
1
2
2
3
3
4
5
6
7
8

Mean: 4.1
Mode: [2, 3]
Median: 3.5
Standard Deviation: 2.211334
```